# Should all pods using a redis cache be constrained to the same node as the rediscache itself?

Tags: redis, kubernetes

We are running one of our services in a newly created kubernetes cluster. Because of that, we have now switched them from the previous "in-memory" cache to a Redis cache.

Preliminary tests on our application which exposes an API shows that we experience timeouts from our applications to the Redis cache. I have no idea why and it issue pops up very irregularly.

So I'm thinking maybe the reason for these timeouts are actually network related. Is it a good idea to put in affinity so we always run the Redis-cache on the same nodes as the application to prevent network issues?

The issues have not arisen during "very high load" situations so it's concerning me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion question so I'll answer in an opinionated way:

Like you mentioned I would try to put the Redis and application pods on the same node, that would rule out `wire` networking issues. You can accomplish that with [Kubernetes pod affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity). But you can also try [nodeslector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), that way you always pin your Redis and application pods to a specific node.

Another way to do this is to [taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) your nodes where you want to run your workloads and then add a toleration to the Redis and your application pods.

Hope it helps!